# Web Automation not running in jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

Why my jenkins job is not executing my Web Test.

Web Test is written in JAVA selenium web Driver
Im using maven plugin aswell

I use some annotation to category my test. something like this

```
public interface FastTests {
 }

 public interface SlowTests {
 }

 public static class A {
        @Test
        public void a() {
                fail();
        }

        @Category(SlowTests.class)
        @Test
        public void b() {
        }
 }

 @Category( { SlowTests.class, FastTests.class })
 public static class B {
        @Test
        public void c() {

        }
 }

 @RunWith(Categories.class)
 @IncludeCategory(SlowTests.class)
 @SuiteClasses( { A.class, B.class })
 // Note that Categories is a kind of Suite
 public static class SlowTestSuite {
 }
```

JENKINS ERROR

```
09:36:32 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project mpqa-webloader: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
09:36:32 [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Jenkins\workspace\WebAutomationWindows\web\pom.xml to com.mpayme.testkit/mpqa-webloader/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mpqa-webloader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
09:36:32 [ERROR] 
09:36:32 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
09:36:32 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
09:36:32 [ERROR] 
09:36:32 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
09:36:32 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException`
```

please help where i did wrong? thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

First you should name your tests according to the naming convention rules in Maven which means things like [`WhatEverTest.java`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes). If you really need suites to define tests you should use the parameters of the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) instead of defining that in code which is documented in the [documentation of maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_JUnit_Categories).

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <groups>com.example.FastTests,com.example.RegressionTests</groups>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Apart from that it sounds you need to make a separation between unit and integration testing, cause things like slow tests sounds like integration tests which should be handled by the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) instead. In particular if we are talking about selenium tests which are by definition integration tests.